# The pronunciation of "try to" vs. "tried to"

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I know that *try to* is pronounced /tɹaɪɾə/, but how is *tried to* pronounced?

It wouldn't make sense for it to have the same pronunciation, because then we wouldn't be able to differentiate between those two, since context might not be enough. Is it the vowel length?

I was thinking maybe /tɹaɪdtə/, but I'm not sure.

Comment: They might not be quite the same, but they're very similar. However, context is usually enough. Consider *put* (past tense) and *put* (present tense). How are you going to distinguish those without context?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about "put". Now that I think about it it really isn't that hard to differentiate by context. But either way, do you know what's the difference between thise two?

Comment: The two sound *almost* the same, except that there is a *very abbreviated* "D" sound in "tried to".  The tongue position is slightly different between the two.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean by different tongue positions? Aren't they both supposed to be alveolar?

Comment: @Phonsar - I said *slightly* different.  And that slight difference makes all the difference.  The tongue touches the roof of the mouth slightly farther back when you say "tried to".  The tongue also touches the roof twice.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh my bad, didn't see that. And also what do you mean by touching the roof twice?

Comment: @Phonsar - Twice, as in "two times".

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry I should've explained better, I mean touching the roof twice in what way, you mean something like /tɹaɪdɾə/?

Comment: I mean both the D and the T sounds produce a touch.  I have no idea what /tɹaɪdɾə/ is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For most North Americans, excepting only the Deep South, [*Canadian Raising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising) applies to *try to* [ˈt͡ʂɻʷ**ʌɪ**ɾə] — but **not** to *tried to*, which is just the un-raised form [ˈt͡ʂɻʷ**aɪ**ɾə].  This is the same thing that happens between *writer* and *rider*, despite both being flaps; the one that originally had a /t/ is raised.

The diphthong in *tried to* is also held longer than the one in *try to*. I think this may be because of the original /d/ phoneme at the end of *tried*, which assimilates into the merged flap of *tried to*.  As Peter Shor observes, *trite* is probably a better example of Canadian Raising.

For the record, I have the [Inland North accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English) of the Great Lakes, so plenty of Canadian Raising and no *cot–caught* merge. However, I don’t have the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift).

Comment: Really? I would have thought Canadian Raising would treat both of them the same. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising): *Canadian raising affects vowels before voiceless consonants like /f/, /θ/, /t/, and /s/.* But tried ends with /d/. I certainly pronounce the vowel in trite slightly differently than the one in try or tried, but I suppose this might work differently depending on your accent.

Comment: Ah ... maybe you raise the vowel in *try to* because in *try to* it's followed by a /t/. I don't—the vowel and consonant have to be in the same word for it to be raised in my speech.

Comment: @PeterShor Now that you mention it, *trite* does seem a little different: shorter maybe; perhaps it’s the real [t] on the end. I think the lengthening effect from the *tried* may be more noticeable than the raising in *try to*, which I agree doesn’t seem so high with *try to* as it does in *trite*. I have an Inland North accent but without the Northern Cities Vowel Shift.

Answer (score 1):

The two are easily  distinguibile in  pronunciation. (Context could help if a speaker does not enunciate clearly.)

*tried to* has a distinct *d* sound not heard in *try to*. And yes, the vowel length is probably longer in the latter.

For instance, *I try to  brush my teeth* and *I tried to brush my teeth* are easily distinguished by listening.

I can't find two sentences that are the same except for *try to/tried to*, but the following may help:

try to -> http://forvo.com/phrase/i_might_try_to_explain/

tried to -> http://forvo.com/phrase/she_tried_to_reach_the_vase_but_overbalanced_and_fell_off_the_stool./

Note the speakers above speak at s different rate, so it's not s perfect comparison, but it should illustrate the difference. Of course, the ending *t* in *might* is not pronounced fully before the beginning *t* of *try to*, unless the speaker is deliberately  speaking slowly and stressing each word.

Comment: These are two different speakers talking with two completely different accents. I don't think it's very helpful. And it's easy to distinguish them in British English, but not in American English, because *try to* has /t/ and *tried to* has /d/. Could you explain how *tried to* differs from *try to*. Is it the vowel or the consonant?

Comment: nope, that's the best I can do. meanwhile no one else has yet answered